# PHP mysql_connect cannot resolve Host name when sessions are enabled

Tags: php, mysql, session

Crazy right? Sample code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$hostname="samplehost";
$username="sampleuser";
$password="samplepass";
$dbname="sampledb";

$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname, $link);
?>
```

Will throw `Unknown MySQL server host 'samplehost' (2)`.  If we remove the `session_start()` or just do a `session_destroy()` before the `mysql_connect()`, it works correctly.  Basically, if we have a session open, its like mysql_connect wont resolve the host name. The host name we use for the server is correctly added to /etc/hosts.

It's a production server running PHP 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.7 - just started happening today.  Anyone run into this?

edit:  should mention, with or without sessions, we can specify the IP of the DB server, and it works correctly.

Comment: Is this the full script (minus values, of course) that you're testing this with?

Comment: are all DNS/hosts operations impacted? What about gethostbyname()?

Comment: Have you tried resolving other hosts besides your entry in /etc/hosts ?

Comment: @Richard - This is a script that I have tested with, verbatim - to limit all other sources.  @Capsule - oddly enough, we have tried that, not ALL DNS is effected, we can use `gethostbyname()` does return the correct IP.  @Payson - yes, doesn't matter what we put in for a host, it just doesn't resolve.

Comment: It appears you aren't the first person to run across this.  I don't see anything that says it's fixed: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone comes across this - it turns out to be a an issue with the amount of Virtual Hosts we had in Apache.  Appears when you start hitting the limit on file descriptors, you get some odd symptoms - it was finally diagnosed when we started getting a 'Too many open files' error in PHP.

It was a legacy setup in how we were automatically generating vhosts for new domains.  Better managed that process, reduce the amount of vhosts and the issues went away.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just connect first, then start the session?